# new installation pdflatex hangs

Tags: pdftex, miktex

I have just reinstalled MiKTeX 2.9.6630 (twice) as admin on a Win 7 PC. Went to the console and checked for and updated packages. But every time I try to compile

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Test}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
Test document.
\end{document}
```

> pdflatex test.tex pdflatex: warning: running with administrator privileges
>   This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6630 64-bit)

and then it hangs. The log file gives

> 2018-03-27 19:12:16,150+1030 INFO  pdflatex - starting with command
>   line: "C:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe" test.tex 2018-03-27
>   19:12:16,150+1030 WARN  pdflatex - running with administrator
>   privileges 2018-03-27 19:12:16,160+1030 INFO  pdflatex - allowing
>   known shell commands 2018-03-27 19:12:16,160+1030 INFO  pdflatex -
>   enabling input (output) from (to) processes 2018-03-27
>   19:12:16,200+1030 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt

And I have no idea why. Can anyne help?

Comment: It seems to have problems to create the fmt. Instead asking here better open an issue at the miktex issue tracker on github.

Comment: did you managed to solve this? I'm having the same problem